# mySql query with groupBy on same field filtered in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, group-by

I can't explain why, given this two queries,

```
SELECT YEAR(TIMESTAMP) AS YEAR,
       MONTH(TIMESTAMP) AS MONTH,
       DAY(TIMESTAMP) AS DAY,
       COUNT(IDENTITY) AS number,
       type
FROM entity AS e,
     annotation AS a
WHERE e.annotationIdAnnotation = a.idAnnotation
  AND type = "Location"
GROUP BY YEAR(TIMESTAMP),
         MONTH(TIMESTAMP),
         DAY(TIMESTAMP),
         type


SELECT YEAR(TIMESTAMP) AS YEAR,
       MONTH(TIMESTAMP) AS MONTH,
       DAY(TIMESTAMP) AS DAY,
       COUNT(IDENTITY) AS number
FROM entity AS e,
     annotation AS a
WHERE e.annotationIdAnnotation = a.idAnnotation
  AND type = "Location"
GROUP BY YEAR(TIMESTAMP),
         MONTH(TIMESTAMP),
         DAY(TIMESTAMP)
```

the second one takes the 100% more of the first one.
I have a btree index on type, but I can't explain why the group by on a field already filtered by the where clause could enhance the performance of the query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is very straight and simple reason for it.
As you said you have the index on type column. So index make the query fast.

And in the first query you are using the type, that is in the index, in `where and GROUP by` clause but in the second one you are using the type in only `where` clause. So in the first query the type using in the `GROUP BY` clause make the query fast as in reduce the number of rows and make a group of rows to select.

For more information about the index [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

This link will clear more things.

This is reason for what the first query is fast than the second one.

Comment: The index is used in both cases, as I could see with the EXPLAIN statement, and I verified that first query without the type in the select is performing in the same way.

Comment: @user2088847 I have edited the answer and add a link check that which will clear your doubts.